# glReadPixels() read wrong value

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glad

currently, I am trying to read back the data I transfer to texture in OpenGL. However, I do not receive the correct result. Where do I wrong?

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
const int SCR_WIDTH = 600;
const int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;
int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    int texSize = 2;
    const int Size = texSize*texSize*4;
    float *data = new float[Size];
    float *result = new float[Size];
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++){
        data[i] = i + 1.0;
    }
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLuint fbo;
    glGenFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLuint text;
    glGenTextures(1,&text);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,text);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, GL_RGBA, texSize, texSize, 0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,data);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D,text, 0);


    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glReadPixels(0, 0, texSize, texSize,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,result);
    std::cout<<"Data before roundtrip:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<texSize*texSize*4; i++)
        std::cout<<"\n"<<data[i];
    std::cout<<"\nData after roundtrip:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<texSize*texSize*4; i++)
        std::cout<<"\n"<<result[i];
    // clean up
    free(data);
    free(result);
    glDeleteFramebuffers (1,&fbo);
    glDeleteTextures (1,&text);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;


}
```

Here is the result:

```
Data before roundtrip:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
Data after roundtrip:

1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

This is not the result I expected. I expected both data and result are the same

I have looked it up on the internet but still no result or explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

`glReadPixels` does not read the wrong values, i would be surprised if that would be the case.

You expect the returned values to be the same as those you passed to `glTexImage2D` and that is a misconception, because the data in your client memory gets unpacked by GL and converted to the internal format based on the specified type (see: [8.4.4 Transfer of Pixel Rectangles](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#subsection.8.4.4)).

In short, if your data type is `GL_FLOAT`, then the values in your data array have to be in the range `[0.0f , 1.0f]`, otherwise every value below and beyond gets clamped to this range. Since your values are above `1.0f`, clamping does occur and therefore the values will be interpreted as `1.0f` and that is the value you get from `glReadPixels`.

So, either you divide each component by `255.0f` or use one of the integer types, e.g. `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

Answer (score 0):

The internal format of the framebuffer texture is `GL_RGBA`, this format can only store values in range [0.0, 1.0]. Note, the 7th and 8th argument of `glTexImage2D` (`GL_RGBA`, `GL_FLOAT`) just specify the format of the source data, but not the internal format of the data store. You have to use one of the
sized internal formats (see [`glTexImage2D`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)). e.g. `GL_RGBA32F`:

<s>`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, GL_RGBA, texSize, texSize, 0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,data);`</s>

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, texSize, texSize, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
```